# getting multiple user inputs

Tags: string, scala, function

```
def move(s: String){

if(s.equals("l")){
  al()
}else if(s.equals("r")){
  ar()
}else if(s.equals("u")){
  au()
}else if(s.equals("d")){
  ad()
} }
```

the code above is something I have tried but doesn't work. It should be able to get multiple strings like (lrudd) in one line and each letter equals to a function. 
so if lrudd is entered the al(), ar(), au(), ad(), ad() function should be done, its a 2d game so the player should move al()- which is left, ar()- which is right, ar()- which up and ad(),twice as down is entered twice (dd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to `map()` over the `String` in order to evaluate each `Char` individually.

```
def move(s: String) = s.map {
  case 'l' => al()
  case 'r' => ar()
  case 'u' => au()
  case 'd' => ad()
  case  _  => //report error
}
```